# Setting Magento admin configuration via local.xml

Tags: magento

Is it possible to set Magento configuration that is normally configured via admin->System->Configuration via the app/etc/local.xml or app/etc/config.xml?

Effectively allowing a set of default configuration that could be used to start a fresh Magento install.

Any advice in this area or location of suitable reference would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default configuration values can be set in config.xml.

See default section:

`<default>
        <system>
            <filesystem>
                <base>{{root_dir}}</base>
                <app>{{root_dir}}/app</app>
                <code>{{app_dir}}/code</code>
                <design>{{app_dir}}/design</design>
                <locale>{{app_dir}}/locale</locale>
                <etc>{{app_dir}}/etc</etc>
                <media>{{root_dir}}/media</media>
                <upload>{{root_dir}}/media/upload</upload>
                <skin>{{root_dir}}/skin</skin>
                <var>{{var_dir}}</var>
                <cache>{{var_dir}}/cache</cache>
                <session>{{var_dir}}/session</session>
                <tmp>{{var_dir}}/tmp</tmp>
                <pear>{{var_dir}}/pear</pear>
                <export>{{var_dir}}/export</export>
            </filesystem>
        </system>
        <general>
            <locale>
                <code>en_GB</code>
                <timezone>Europe/London</timezone>
            </locale>
        </general>
    </default>`

Expand the above structure to include other configurational defaults, any specified here will be used on clean installation.

For systems already in use / configured, update the configuration via MySQL see: core_config

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with a script, "devsetup.php" and put it in the root of your magento folder,

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

$config = new Mage_Core_Model_Config();

$options = array(
    'design/theme/template' => 'custom',
    'design/theme/skin' => 'custom',
    'design/theme/layout' => 'custom',
    'log/dev/active' => '1'
);

foreach($options as $key => $value){ 
    $config->saveConfig($key,$value,"default",0); 
}
?>
```

worth saying this is totally untested, but the theory is sound ;)